# Comparing and extrating data from two tables in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a project and I need to write a query in which I can list all courses that have "Database System Principles" as prerequisite
There are two tables one is by name course and other is by name prereqs which contain information about courses that which course has how many and which pre-requisites

Please click to check the two tables here:

[image]

Comment: Have you taken "Database System Principles"?  If you had, you might be able to better write the query.

Comment: I am confused what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Select * from Course as c JOIN prereqs on c.course_ID = prereqs.course_ID WHERE c.name = "Database System Principles"
```

Comment: returned an empty set

Comment: I changed your query a little bit and now I got it :)

Comment: @MalikShahroze if your problem solved then select answer

Comment: SELECT name FROM course WHERE course_ID IN (SELECT a.course_ID FROM prereqs a JOIN course b ON a.pre_req = b.course_id WHERE b.name = 'Database System Principle') 
this is it